# Calculate Landau's function

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, permutations, integer-partitions

[Landau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function) \$g(n)\$ ([OEIS A000793](https://oeis.org/A000793)) gives the maximum order of an element of the symmetric group \$S_n\$.  Here, the order of a permutation \$\pi\$ is the smallest positive integer \$k\$ such that \$\pi^k\$ is the identity - which is equal to the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles in the permutation's cycle decomposition.  For example, \$g(14) = 84\$ which is achieved for example by (1,2,3)(4,5,6,7)(8,9,10,11,12,13,14).

Therefore, \$g(n)\$ is also equal to the maximum value of \$\operatorname{lcm}(a_1, \ldots, a_k)\$ where \$a_1 + \cdots + a_k = n\$ with \$a_1, \ldots, a_k\$ positive integers.

### Problem

Write a function or program that calculates Landau's function.

### Input

A positive integer \$n\$.

### Output

\$g(n)\$, the maximum order of an element of the symmetric group \$S_n\$.

### Examples

```
n    g(n)
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    6
6    6
7    12
8    15
9    20
10   30
11   30
12   60
13   60
14   84
15   105
16   140
17   210
18   210
19   420
20   420
```

### Score

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): Shortest program in bytes wins.  (Nevertheless, shortest implementations in multiple languages are welcome.)

Note that there are no requirements imposed on run-time; therefore, your implementation does not necessarily need to be able to generate all the above example results in any reasonable time.

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
Åœ€.¿Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9s4O5nr6Sga6egZO/3/3Dr0cmPmtboHdof9V/nv/l/Xd28fN2cxKpKAA)

```
    Åœ       # integer partitions of the input
      €.¿    # lcm of each
         Z   # maximum
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 44 bytes

```
Max[PermutationOrder/@Permutations@Range@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Ng@983sSI6ILUot7QEKJaf51@Uklqk74AkUuwQlJiXnuqgHKv2P6AoM68kWlnXzidaOTZWTUHfQQEsGW1oEPsfAA)

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

@DanielSchepler has a better solution:

```
Max[LCM@@@IntegerPartitions@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Ng@983sSLax9nXwcHBM68kNT21KCCxqCSzJDM/r9hBOVbtf0BRZl5JtLKunU@0cmysmoK@g0JQYl56arSRQex/AA)

Comment: Not that familiar with the language - but `Max[Apply@LCM/@IntegerPartitions@#]&` seems to work for me and would give 36 bytes if it's correct.

Comment: @DanielSchepler yes, super! Why don't you propose it as a separate solution? You can even do `Max[LCM@@@IntegerPartitions@#]&` for [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Ng@983sSLax9nXwcHBM68kNT21KCCxqCSzJDM/r9hBOVbtf0BRZl5JtLKunU@0cmysmoK@g0JQYl56arSRQex/AA), because `@@@` does `Apply` at level 1.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 44 bytes

```hs
(%1)
n%t=maximum$t:[(n-d)%lcm t d|d<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX0PVUJMrT7XENjexIjO3NFelxCpaI083RVM1JzlXoUQhpSbFRjfaUE8vLzb2f25iZp6CrUJuYoGvQkFRZl6JggqIo5CmAFJhaBD7/19yWk5ievF/3eSCAgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 87 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,d=1:max([f(m,min(range(d,d<<n,d),key=(n-m).__rmod__))for m in range(n)]+[d])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcoxDoMwDEDRuT1FRluYSmk3RE6CUJTKpI1aOyhigNMHKoau7/95W95Z77VG9w3y5GCU2NlOwgpDBCFJCiXoawIm7vujIn2mzYG2gjfvi2T2HjHmYsQkNeesODYDj1h/rn@3ZB/YXS9zSbpAPD6sOw)

A recursive function that tracks the remaining `n` to partition and the running LCM `d`. Note that this means we don't need to track the actual numbers in the partition or how many of them we've used. We try each possible next part, `n-m`, replacing `n` with what's left `m`, and `d` with `lcm(d,n-m)`. We take the maximum of those recursive results and `d` itself. When nothing remains `n=0`, the result ist just `d`.

The tricky thing is that Python doesn't have any built-ins for LCM, GCD, or prime factorization. To do `lcm(d,m-n)`, we generate a list of multiples of `d`, and take the value attaining the minimum modulo `n-m`, that is with `key=(n-m).__rmod__`. Since `min` will give the earlier value in case of a tie, this is always the first nonzero multiple of `d` that's divisible by `n-m`, so their LCM. We only multiples of `d` up to `d*(n-m)` to be guaranteed to hit the LCM, but it's shorter to write `d<<n` (which is `d*2**n`) which suffices with Python's upper bounds being exclusive.

Python 3's `math` library has `gcd` (but not `lcm`) after 3.5, which is a few bytes shorter. Thanks to @Joel for shortening the import.

**[Python 3.5+](https://docs.python.org/3/), 84 bytes**

```python
import math
f=lambda n,d=1:max([f(m,d*(n-m)//math.gcd(n-m,d))for m in range(n)]+[d])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcoxDsIwDEDRmZ7Cow2BKupWqSepOhhM2kjYiaIMcPpAJsb/9POnHsmm1qLmVCoo12MIy4v1LgzmZPGz8hvXgOrkjHZVGsd@3faH9HRCFFIBhWhQ2PYnGm2XVTZq3e3v3vmJ5uGUS7SK4fdR@wI)

Using `numpy`'s `lcm` is yet shorter.

**Python with [numpy](https://numpy.org/), 77 bytes**

```python
from numpy import*
f=lambda n,d=1:max([f(m,lcm(d,n-m))for m in range(n)]+[d])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcoxDoMwDADAubzCo03DEEYkXoIY0ga3kbATWalUXp@WifV05ajvrGNrbFlAP1IOSFKy1b7jeQ/yiAHUxdlPEr64MIrbn4LR6SBEnA0EkoIFfW2otN6XuFI7XS/3znuauluxpBX5/6j9AA)

Comment: Using `from math import*` is 85 bytes and using `import math` + `math.gcd(...)` is 84 bytes. The same applies to `numpy`.

Comment: @Joel Thanks, I forgot about that.

Comment: @Joel Thanks, I had forgotten to update the byte count, they're both 77. `numpy`'s length of 5 is the [break-even point](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52317/20260) for `import*`.

Comment: Right. In that case I prefer to use `import numpy` because `numpy.max` would override Python's built-in `max` (same for `min`) if `from numpy import*` is used. It does not cause problems here but we all know that `import*` is not a good programming practice in general.

Comment: @Joel While `import*` is no doubt bad practice, I don't think it actually overwrites Python's `min` and `max`, so the confusion would be someone expecting numpy's function and getting the base one.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I saw a warning about that in an earlier version of `numpy`. Maybe in the newer versions the behavior has changed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Œṗæl/€Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7px9elqP/qGnNw50N/60fNcxR0LVTeNQw1/pwO5eRweF2oEzkfwA)

A monadic link taking an integer as its argument and returning an integer.

### Explanation

```
Œṗ      | Integer partitions
  æl/€  | Reduce each using LCM
      Ṁ | Maximum
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

Computes the maximum value of \$\operatorname{lcm}(a_1,\ldots,a_k)\$ where \$a_1+\ldots+a_k\$ is a partition of \$n\$.

```javascript
f=(n,i=1,l=m=0)=>n?i>n?m:f(n-i,i,l*i/(G=(a,b)=>b?G(b,a%b):a)(l,i)||i)&f(n,i+1,l)|m:m=l>m?l:m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczNDoIwEATgu0/RA5pdKQrxVlw48hq0CGZNfwwYL8Cz13qYZJKZfC/91csw8/tT@PAYY5wIvGSqpCVHJVLjW05xagJfsGRpz3yFjkBLk1bTdmCkPhpUGsFKxm1jPE1/JE8Ibk45so1rrXJxCjN4QaKqhRd3ErcylTxHsR6EGIJfgh0vNjyh15Ctfsf0zdaE4d5jfdjjDw)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 95 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=1,m)=>i>>n?m:f(n,i+1,i<m|(g=(n,k=2,p=0)=>k>n?p:n%k?p+g(n,k+1):g(n/k,k,p*k||k))(i)>n?m:i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5LDoMwEEP3nGIWVMo06ScsgcBVQBRQOjCJoOoGOHsaurJlP1l@t9927RbrPzd2rz6EwQhW1mg1o6lsVXE958MZSa1sOe9iPAEymfLmGRGKhM/5QrWX49lIjXk0D1Kk/JX2nRCFxf@QxTC4RTAY0AUwlKCzqFIibAlA53h1U3@f3CiaVqQbHxjRdIsH8GiwSI7wAw)

#### How?

We define:

$$\cases{
g(1)=0\\
g(n)=\sum_{j=1}^{N}{p_j}^{k_j}\quad\text{for}\enspace n>1\enspace\text{and}\enspace n=\prod_{j=1}^{N}{p_j}^{k_j}
}$$

(this is [A008475](https://oeis.org/A008475))

Then we use the formula (from [A000793](https://oeis.org/A000793)):

$$f(n)=\max_{g(k)\le n}k$$

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 50 bytes

```perl6
{max .map:{+(.[$_],{.[@^a]}...$_,)}}o&permutations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OjexQkEvN7HAqlpbQy9aJT5Wp1ov2iEuMbZWT09PJV5Hs7Y2X60gtSi3tCSxJDM/r/i/NVdxYqWCkkq8gq2dQrWCHtCcWiWFtPwiBUM9PfP/AA)

Checks all permutations directly, like @histocrat's Ruby solution.

#### Explanation

```perl6
                                     &permutations  # Permutations of [0;n)
{                                  }o  # Feed into block
     .map:{                       }  # Map permutations
                           ...  # Construct sequence
             .[$_]  # Start with permutation applied to itself [1]
                  ,{.[@^a]}  # Generate next item by applying permutation again
                              $_,  # Until it matches original permutation [2]
           +(                    )  # Length of sequence
 max  # Find maximum
```

<sup>1</sup> We can use any sequence of n distinct items for the check, so we simply take the permutation itself.

<sup>2</sup> If the endpoint is a container, the `...` sequence operator smartmatches against the first item. So we have to pass a single-element list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
,:Π¤d¦&⊢⌉/
1w&ḍΣ¦¦⇈⊢¦⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/X8fq3IJDS1IOLVN71LXoUU@nPpdhudrDHb3nFh9admjZo/YOoDCQ7un8/98UAA)

Not having LCM or integer partitions makes this approach rather long.

```
,:Π¤d¦&⊢⌉/		;* helper function: LCM of 2 inputs


1w&ḍΣ¦¦			;* push integer partitions
         ¦		;* for each
       ⇈⊢		;* Reduce by helper function
	  ⌉		;* and take the max
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 77 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{a=*0...n;a.permutation.map{|p|(1..).find{a.map!{|i|p[i]}==a.sort}}.max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZgtEunZ51Ym2WgZ6enp51ol6BalFuaUliSWZ@Xl6uYkF1TUFNRqGenoqKpp6aZl5KdWJIFHF6prMmoLozNhaW9tEveL8opLaWqB4Re3/gtKSYgWQBgtNiPaKmrToitja/wA)

`(1..)` infinite range syntax is too new for TIO, so the link sets an arbitrary upper bound.

This uses the direct definition--enumerate all possible permutations, then test each one by mutating `a` until it gets back to its original position (which also conveniently means I can just mutate the original array in each loop).

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>70</s> 67 bytes

```
f n=maximum[foldl1 lcm a|k<-[1..n],a<-mapM id$[1..n]<$[1..k],sum a==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpNCoAgEEDhq8zSIIV2EXmEThASQyWJM1P0Ay26uyWtHg@@BY84E6XkQSzjHfji3q80UQU0MuATW91XxogrsdWMW6ea/4uc6Mrj@pi14hJjELCQ0QBq24OcxheQXe3SCw)

Edit: -3 bytes thanks to @xnor.

Comment: I think it should work to do `mapM(:[1..n])`, since the extra element is harmless.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + numpy, <strike>115</strike> <strike>102</strike> 99 bytes

*-13 bytes thanks to @Daniel Shepler*

*-3 more bytes from @Daniel Shepler*

```python
import numpy
c=lambda n:[n]+[numpy.lcm(i,j)for i in range(1,n)for j in c(n-i)]
l=lambda n:max(c(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcw7DoMwEEXRnlVMOVYAkaRDYiWIwji/QZ5ny3KksHpDaCjvKW5c8yfgXopoDCkTvhrXyg3e6vywhH7EdBkPbb1Tlnoxr5BISEDJ4v3ka42Dlj85RiNmqvx5UPvjnY0pMQkye751e2w)

Brute force method: find all possible sequences a,b,c,... where a+b+c+...=n, then pick the one with the highest lcm.

Comment: Incidentally, I have a Python 3 + numpy solution running 87 bytes.

Comment: I don't know enough about numpy to figure out how to do that, so I suggest you just post your solution separately.

Comment: Well, I was planning to wait for a while to post it.

Comment: I just realized you posted this challenge. Sorry, I'll do my best.

Comment: Since it came up, you should not try to run this solution for any input higher than 26, even with caching. After nearly freezing my computer for about two and a half hours, the process was killed without giving out an answer. This is not surprising, since it had to calculate the maximum of summing each of about 2^26 lists, which are not memory efficient.

Comment: If you change `c` to return a set and memoize it doesn't do badly at all (though admittedly it does ungolf a bit): https://tio.run/##RY1BCsIwEEX3PUWWM1CLoiuhV/AKEsfUTkkmIU3AWnr2Ggvq7vM@//0wpd7LcV3ZBR@TkuzCVFFrtbvdtZLzLEuThb3AvHWNJQdcD9j5qFixqKjlYeBQy4aGDyKQHeOClf2LnH5C4Yjfqy4LJe/tWO5@ubExX0lTb6AMRn6Z9uLFIBBWIbIksHDaF8kb

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>24</s> 15  bytes

```
eSm.U/*bZibZd./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzU4Vy9UXyspKjMpKkVP//9/Q3MA)

```
             ./Q  # List of partitions of the input
  m               # map that over lambda d:
   .U       d     # reduce d (with starting value first element of the list) on lambda b,Z:
     /*bZgbZ      # (b * Z) / GCD(b, Z)
 S                # this gives the list of lcms of all partitions. Sort this
e                 # and take the last element (maximum)
```

-9 bytes: paid attention and noticed that Pyth actually has a GCD builtin (`i`).